# Create MIP protection templates or labels

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

We are using MIP SDK to protect our files (encryption with templates and ad-hoc configurations).
After a long search, I didn't find any way to create new templates or heaven labels.
Do you know if is it possible or if Microsoft has this capability in the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Labels can be configured in M365 Compliance center.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide

Templates can be directly created only via PowerShell.

Comment: I know but is it on the roadmap for MIP SDK or for Graph API?